# Broken Pipe - Cannot connect to openERP 6.0.4 server using port 8070

Tags: connection, port, odoo

I have an issue whereby all clients cannot connect to openERP server 6.0.4 using port 8070.

It happened sometimes in a while (4-6 months). I wonder whats the problem, I checked the network traffic, processor, memory of the server, nothing wrong at all But it just happened few times.

When I checked on server logs, the error are same each time I met this issue, as below :

> [2013-04-23 12:33:53,258][Server] ERROR:web-services:netrpc: cannot
>   deliver exception message to client Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/opt/openerp/server/bin/service/netrpc_server.py", line 89, in
>   run
>       ts.mysend(e, exception=True, traceback=tb_s)   File "/opt/openerp/server/bin/tiny_socket.py", line 64, in mysend
>       self.sock.sendall('%8d%s%s' % (len(msg), exception and "1" or "0", msg))   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
>       return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args) error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
>
> [2013-04-23 13:45:56,273][Server] ERROR:http:Could not run do_POST
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/opt/openerp/server/bin/service/websrv_lib.py", line 299, in
>   _handle_one_foreign
>       method()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SimpleXMLRPCServer.py", line 519, in do_POST
>       self.send_response(200)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 396, in send_response
>       (self.protocol_version, code, message))   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 324, in write
>       self.flush()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
>       self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size]) error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer [2013-04-23
>   13:45:56,647][Server] ERROR:http:code 500, message Internal error
>   [2013-04-23 13:45:56,650][Server] ERROR:init:Server error in request
>   from ('192.168.0.132', 1880): Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/opt/openerp/server/bin/service/websrv_lib.py", line 528, in
>   _handle_request2
>       self.process_request(request, client_address)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 310, in process_request
>       self.finish_request(request, client_address)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
>       self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)   File "/opt/openerp/server/bin/service/websrv_lib.py", line 246, in **init**
>       SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler.**init**(self,request,client_address,server)
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 641, in **init**
>       self.finish()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 694, in finish
>       self.wfile.flush()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
>       self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size]) error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Broken-pipe error is a typical socket related error. It maybe if connect to slow from internet to server.

I suggest to use apache proxy to make available local server to internet. Mapping local server LOCALHOST:8069 to www.wxample.net:9000 using VirtualHost setting in apache. It may work for you.

For more information, Have a look at this link:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/openerp-web/+bug/927793

It may be helpful for you.

Comment: But what happen on my environment was openERP 6.0.4 was being used via intranet only, we disabled web platform (because 6.0 used to have python issue on web platform), so all clients are using GTK Client for accessing the server.

Therefore i don't think it's internet issue. And fyi some of my clients don't even have internet connection at all.